# when I map my redux state with component state I am getting an error

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, material-ui

- when you click advanced sports search button I need to display drawer with my api values.
- but right now when I map my redux state with component state I am getting an error.
  Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.
- can you tell me how to map my state.
- so that in future I can fix all my redux issues by myself.
- providing code snippet and sandbox below.
- all my map state is done in tab-demo.js

https://codesandbox.io/s/rlpv50q8qo

```
getSportsPlayerHistory = values => {
    this.props.fetchHistorySportsDatafromURL();
  };

  toggleDrawer = (side, open) => () => {
    if (open === true) {
      this.getSportsPlayerHistory();
    }

    this.setState({
      [side]: open
    });
  };

  const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onDeleteAllSPORTS: () => {
      // console.log("called");
      dispatch(deleteAllPosts());
    },
    addFavoriteSPORTSs: data => {
      dispatch(addFavoriteSPORTSs(data));
    },
    fetchHistorySportsDatafromURL: () => {
      dispatch(fetchHistorySportsDatafromURL());
    }
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actions need to return plain objects, your `fetchHistorySportsDatafromURL` action returns a function.  If you make your history reducer function `async` then you can make an async function to make your API call **there** and return the result to state.

[API call in reducer](https://codesandbox.io/s/40p4k2x929)

- This works, but isn't ideal as you want your reducers to be pure functions, as-in, no side-effects, same input **always** produces the same output

You can also make the API request in the component's callback handler asynchronously and pass the result to the dispatched action.

[API call in component then dispatched in action](https://codesandbox.io/s/o4p04p89z5)

- This is a good solution and works great for small projects, but couples network business logic into your UI display components, which also isn't as ideal since it reduces code re-usability.

If you still want to keep your API logic separate from your component (which is a good thing), [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) is a way to create asynchronous action creators, which is very similar to the pattern of your original code.

[API call in action using redux-thunk](https://codesandbox.io/s/4wo9l6132w)

- This is the most ideal as it completely de-couples business logic from your UI, meaning you can change back-end requests without touching front-end UI, and other components can now also use the same action.  Good DRY principal.

Not really sure what you wanted to do with the new state, but this should get you to a good spot to handle that in your `mapStateToProps` function.

Comment: thanks for your reply...I saw your code changes you have commented the api call, can you update the api call in the sandbox its so confusing :(

Comment: @nossr can you be more specific, I'm not sure what you're asking for.  I commented out the API call in the action so you could see where it was, and where it now resides in the reducer.  What is confusing you?

Comment: when you click advanced sports search button a drawer opens in that drawer I need to make this api call url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments" in redux way  to display data

Comment: @nossr Oops, just realized I never saved the rest of the changes I'd made.  I moved the API code into the reducer and made it an async function.  Sandbox should be good now.  Although I suspect you have a lot more work to do since your drawer seems to close upon __any__ interaction in fields.

Comment: is it anyway can you make the call in actions, since reducers are pure functions we dont make api call there...can you help me

Comment: @nossr No, and yes.  Normally action creators need to return plain objects, but with redux-thunk you can introduce side-effects into your actions.

Comment: so whats the correct way of doing...so that in future I will be doing it correctly...and I didn't understand this line  but with redux-thunk you can introduce side-effects into your actions can you give some more explanation :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185847/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-no-ssr).

Comment: hey sorry I am not able to chat...can you post as a comment I will reply to your comments

Comment: All of the ways I showed are technically "correct" ways of doing it (they work and don't throw errors). I updated my answer to include some reasoning behind using each method. The entire purpose of redux-thunk is to be able to have side effects to your actions, as actions typically coupled with a reducer. This means you dispatch an action (with or without a payload), and your reducer handles it (w/o side-effects because they are pure functions).

Comment: Thunks allow you to do side-effects on your actions like asynchronous calls, delaying them, doing other things, etc...; they allow for more control over the dispatched actions.

Comment: thanks for your detailed explaination still it doesnt display the data in the browser...I need to show the data in this div  <div>reading the data from api{historySports}</div> which is in this file sports-advanced-search.js

Comment: can you give comments inside the sandbox...it will help others too

Comment: Added some commenting.  If I've sufficiently answered your question(s) I would appreciate it being marked as an answer.

Comment: thanks for your detailed explaination still it doesnt display the data in the browser...I need to show the data in this div <div>reading the data from api{historySports}</div> which is in this file sports-advanced-search.js

Comment: It doesn't display it because you don't map sports history from the redux state to any prop (historySports in your case) that sports-advanced-search uses.  If you have further issues with your code please open a new question.  If my answer is sufficient to your question here please accept it.

Comment: can you let me know whow to map it...so that we can close it

Comment: `const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  historySports: state.history
});` and add that to your `connect` function.

Comment: can you update directly to the sandbox.. I tried but its not working

Comment: hey I looked at your code its throwing an error, can you open the drawer and see Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {postId, id, name, email, body}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: I think this is indicative of other problems in your code, also stackoverflow isn't meant to debug your entire app.  Which code sandbox are you looking at?  I tried the last one using redux-thunk, I'm not seeing that error, but I'm also completely unfamiliar with your app so I'm also not sure what you're doing to get the error or how I can repro it.  It really would be better to communicate in chat to work on this, or accept answer that helped the question originally asked here and open a new question for the bug you're seeing.

Comment: hey when you clcik the advanced sports search a drawer opens in that when you click sports attributes tab you will see the error, in trhat tab only we will render the data

Comment: When doing that I only get this warning: `Warning: Failed prop type: The following properties are not supported: \`disableUnderline\`. Please remove them.`

Comment: hey in the console are you not seeing this error when you clcik sports attributes Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {postId, id, name, email, body}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: you can see the error here https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21798150 I have attached as image

Comment: Feel free to please fork and save your sandbox changes and paste a link to a chat here or open a new stackoverflow thread regarding this new error.  I'm running that same sandbox (`4wo9l6132w`) and I'm just not seeing that error you are receiving.  Please accept my answer if I've sufficiently answered your original question.

Comment: can you help me with tgis one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54084760/file-merge-using-react-in-material-ui